# Who benefits most from the laws and/or the judicial system in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

I have always been interested in the law. I was reading an essay by Kenneth Schneyer about the parity of the laws and punishment in Potterverse, titled [*No Place to Stand: The Incoherent Legal World of J. K. Rowling*](https://scholarsarchive.jwu.edu/humanities_fac/28/) and I came across an interesting excerpt that talks about, among other things, law and how it pertains to the characters in *Harry Potter*. Read:

> "Ethnography" is the branch that looks for representations of law *in* literature. The assertion here is that lawyers and judges do not understand how laypersons think or feel about law, or what law *means* to those people. The "majestic equality"<sup>13</sup> of the law, in Anatole France's famous phrase, can mean objectivity and evenhandedness for some, while it means perpetuation of inequality and abuse for others. **What law means in the trenches, what it means to the litigants, what it means to bystanders and witnesses, is typically far removed from what it means to lawyers.**  Literature, by showing us how writers of fiction see legal institutions, can tell us what they mean to "real people."<sup>14</sup>
>
> <sub>*No Place to Stand: The Incoherent Legal World of J. K. Rowling* - Kenneth Schneyer, Professor of Legal Studies - Johnson & Wales University - Presented to Terminus 2008, Chicago, August 9, 2008</sub>

Emphasis added.

Is there parity in Potterverse? Do the higher levels of government make laws without considering the needs and wants of those in the wizarding community with the thought that the lower class(es) won't care. When I say lower class, I'm thinking of, say, the Weasleys, although they are only lower class due to economic reasons. When I think of an upper class family, I think of the Malfoys, who have enough money that neither Lucius or Draco need to work.

**Anyhow, are there examples in canon that demonstrate the Ministry, the Minister for Magic, or the Wizengamot unilaterally passed a law without regard to how it would affect the wizarding community? Are there laws that specifically benefit the upper class in Potterverse to the detriment of the lower class? If so, do they fit the dichotomy taken from *No Place to Stand: The Incoherent Legal World of J. K. Rowling*? What's fair and what's not in Potterverse?**

Comment: Arthur Weasley is a government employee with staff under him, who lives in a five storey detached house with eight bedrooms and its own garden large enough to play Quidditch in. He's hardly *lower* class.

Comment: the legal system reflects the survival mode of the wizarding community is in, i recommend this essay https://pharnabazus.livejournal.com/715.html

Comment: Do educational decrees count?

Comment: are you talking only about humans? The case is made very clearly over the course of the later books that non-wizard classes / races are treated much differently and have different rights and status

Comment: @Valorum - I don't know much about British class definitions, but the books seem to draw a stark contrast between somebody like Malfoy and even Harry and Hermione vs Ron. Over and over again, the reader is shown that the Weasley's have enough to get by, but very little beyond that. They only vacation when they win a prize, Ron doesn't even have any pocket money for his first Hogwart's train ride, they often buy school items second hand or pass them down. Maybe they would be considered lower middle class, but they are definitely intended to be shown as comparatively poor.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Sure. But the Weasley's (relative) poverty seems to relate more to their large number of children rather than Arthur's lack of income. He certainly doesn't fit the standard definition; "*a social group that consists of people who earn little money, often being paid only for the hours or days that they work, and who usually do physical work*". If anything he seems to be "upper middle-class" given his role as a supervisor with a government job, housing situation, the fact that he's able to function as sole income earner, etc

Comment: @NKCampbell - I think the other reason for the "classism" in the Potterverse has to do with blood. The Malfoys are pureblooded and quite proud of that fact. While they look down on the Weasley family for their economic status and size, they also look down on them for assorting themselves with mudbloods and halfbreeds. I could be wrong, but I was always under the impression many of the Ministry of Magic were also purebloods (Weasleys,Umbridge,Fudge,etc.) and while they tolerate those of without pureblood in their society they don't fully accept them either. Kind of like today w/ LGBTQ community

Comment: @NKCampbell - I would be talking about humans *and* other races for purposes of this question (Want to have a go at it?).

Comment: @NKCampbell Malfoy is upper class (landed gentry) along with the Blacks, Weasley is upper-middle class (high-ranked professional [doctor/laywer/civil servant/professor]) as are the senior ministers and teachers. The Potters and the Dursleys are middle class. If you want some lower class characters then see Mundungus Fletcher or Argus Filtch.

Comment: @OrangeDog - Harry's parents left him a small fortune, enough to make Ron envious. They were firmly part of the upper class. As for the Weasley's they are poorer than some people here seem to think. Arthur Weasley's managerial job involved overseeing a very small number of employees in a department that the Ministry (and he himself, for that manner) almost treated like a joke. Magic enables the construction of a large (low-quality house) and allows them to have more than enough food, but they can't afford most things of value in magical society.

Comment: @Adamant no they weren't. Class isn't based on how much money you have, it's who your parents were (and their parents) and what jobs you and they had.

Comment: @OrangeDog - Perhaps in the United Kingdom, granted. In that case, Harry's father was from a long line of pureblood families known as the "Sacred 28." Their jobs, as I recall, were primarily "the idle rich." Close enough for you? By contrast, Mr. Weasley's job was among the most mocked and least valued in the magical world, and yes, its compensation amply reflected its perceived value to society. Many old pureblood families (the upper class) considered him more or less a traitor to magical society just for doing it.

Comment: If we ignore the class issue for just a moment, the Wizengamot scene in *Order of the Phoenix* strikes me as a very obvious example of the law being twisted to serve the interests of the Minister for Magic. Indeed, the whole book could qualify.

Comment: @Adamant Harry's grandfather made the fortune by inventing some popular potions. It was not ancestral inheritance from land ownership. It's firmly middle class. Arthur is a civil service department head (though a small department yes). That's firmly upper-middle class.

Comment: The entire series is depicted overwhelmingly from the point of view of minors, and their awareness of the legal system is heavily colored by their personal experience.  It's probably impossible to come up with an objective description of how the law works.  Let alone whom it favors.